# Computational complexity of Canny edge detector

Tags: edge-detection

I have used a canny edge detector in my paper for the comparison. In the paper, I need to write the computational complexity of a Canny edge detector. The problem is that nowhere on the web, I could not find any reference about the computational complexity of canny. I've even read the original canny paper. I am unable to deduce it properly and need some help here.

Comment: It is not really the place for this question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Time complexity of Canny edge detector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17458237/time-complexity-of-canny-edge-detector)

Answer (score 0):

The detector applies a constant size filter around every pixel, then performs non maxima detection, which is also performed in constant time. The final step of hysteresis thresholding is less easy to evaluate, as it can be implemented in different ways. But it is not unreasonable to consider that the cost is at most proportional to the number of pixels.

So O(N), where N is the image size (in pixels).